# Having problems with new operator in my member functions with stacks

Tags: c++, function, stack, member

I am having problems with my member functions that I am learning stacks with. I can't use templates for this, which is why I am having problems. I can't seem to get a `tempStack` created properly I believe. I have tried using `Element300` and `Stack300` both give me compiler errors that are different. If I can get some help that would be great. Also if you find any other errors let me know. My friend has is having trouble with the `push` function. Which I can't help him with because of my issues regarding `tempStack`.

Header File:

```
    typedef float Element300;

class Stack300
{
    private:
        const int MAX_STACK;
        Element300 * stackArray;
        int top;

    public:
        Stack300();//
        Stack300(int);//
        Stack300(Stack300 &);//
        ~Stack300();//
        void push300(const Element300);//
        Element300 pop300();//
        void viewTB300();
        void viewBT300();
        bool isFull();//
        bool isEmpty();//
    };
```

Member functions:

```
    using namespace std;


Stack300::Stack300(): MAX_STACK(3)
{
    stackArray = new(std::nothrow) Element300[MAX_STACK];
    if(stackArray == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "There is not enough memory for this stack. This stack will not be implemented correctly." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
    top = -1;
    }
}

Stack300::Stack300(int size): MAX_STACK(size)
{
    stackArray = new Element300[MAX_STACK];
    top = -1;
}

Stack300::Stack300(Stack300 & old)
{
    Element300 * tempStack;
    int tempTop = -1;
    Element300 tempValue;
    int tempSize = old.MAX_STACK;

    tempStack = new(std::nothrow) Element300[tempSize];

    while(tempTop <= old.MAX_STACK)
    {
        tempValue = old.pop300();
        tempStack.push300(tempValue);
    }

    while(top <= tempStack.MAX_STACK)
    {
        tempValue = tempStack.pop300();
        old.push300(tempValue);
    }

}
Stack300::~Stack300()
{
    Element300 tempValue;

    while(!isEmpty())
    {
        tempValue = pop300();
    }

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        delete [] stackArray;
    }
}

void Stack300::push300(const Element300 number)
{
    if(isFull())
    {
        cerr << "The stack is full." << endl << "The push was unsuccessful" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        stackArray[top] = number;
    }
    return;
}
Element300 Stack300::pop300()
{
    Element300 number = 0.0;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        cerr << "The stack is empty" << endl << "The pop was unsuccessful" << endl;
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        number = stackArray[top];
        top--;
        return number;
    }
}

void Stack300::viewTB300()
{
    Element300 * tempStack = new (std::nothrow)Element300[MAX_STACK];
    Element300 tempValue;

    while(top > 0)
    {
        tempValue = pop300();
        tempStack.push300(tempValue);
        cout << tempValue << endl;
    }
    while(top < MAX_STACK)
    {
        tempValue = tempStack.pop300();
        push300(tempValue);
    }

    return;
}

void Stack300::viewBT300()
{
    Element300 * tempStack = new (std::nothrow)Element300[MAX_STACK];

    Element300 tempValue;

    while(top > 0)
    {
        tempValue = pop300();
        tempStack.push300(tempValue);
    }
    while(top < MAX_STACK)
    {
        tempValue = tempStack.pop300();
        cout << tempValue << endl;
        push300(tempValue);
    }

}

bool Stack300::isFull()
{
    bool status;

    if(top == MAX_STACK - 1)
        {
            status = true;
        }
    else
    {
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}

bool Stack300::isEmpty()
{
    bool status;

    if(top == - 1)
    {
        status = true;
    }
    else
    {
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Also here are my errors I am getting:

```
    olsond2.cpp: In copy constructor ‘Stack300::Stack300(Stack300&)’:
olsond2.cpp:26: error: uninitialized member ‘Stack300::MAX_STACK’ with ‘const’ type ‘const int’
olsond2.cpp:38: error: request for member ‘push300’ in ‘tempStack’, which is of non-class type ‘Element300*’
olsond2.cpp:41: error: request for member ‘MAX_STACK’ in ‘tempStack’, which is of non-class type ‘Element300*’
olsond2.cpp:43: error: request for member ‘pop300’ in ‘tempStack’, which is of non-class type ‘Element300*’
olsond2.cpp: In member function ‘void Stack300::viewTB300()’:
olsond2.cpp:101: error: request for member ‘push300’ in ‘tempStack’, which is of non-class type ‘Element300*’
olsond2.cpp:106: error: request for member ‘pop300’ in ‘tempStack’, which is of non-class type ‘Element300*’
olsond2.cpp: In member function ‘void Stack300::viewBT300()’:
olsond2.cpp:122: error: request for member ‘push300’ in ‘tempStack’, which is of non-class type ‘Element300*’
olsond2.cpp:126: error: request for member ‘pop300’ in ‘tempStack’, which is of non-class type ‘Element300*’
```

Comment: It's exactly as the compiler says - you're trying to call methods on `tempStack`, which is of type `float*`.

Comment: @Yuushi What do I need to change that?

Comment: You must figure out what you want that function to do, then correct it.

Comment: Do I need to make `tempStack` like this? `Stack300 tempStack = new(std::nothrow) Element300[MAX_STACK]`?

Comment: Alright I am getting closer. I had to make a new object then set it to new. Now I am getting An error on the copy constructor.`olsond2.cpp: In copy constructor ‘Stack300::Stack300(Stack300&)’:
olsond2.cpp:26: error: uninitialized member ‘Stack300::MAX_STACK’ with ‘const’ type ‘const int’`